# Deleteing an image in run time

Tags: wpf, image, delete-file

I am trying to delete an image with the method:
(the file path is correct by 100%)

```
if(File.Exists(filePath))
   File.Delete(filePath);
```

and I am getting the following exception :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'C:\visual_programming\yad2\yad2\bin\Debug\images\1.jpg' because it is being used by another process.

Comment: Have you tried deleting it manually? Can you confirm that it is not in use?

Comment: If you created img by script, make sure than you close file handler first.

Comment: i did try to delete manually and i have no problem deleting manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a common issue for the images that are binded directly to ImageSource of the Image control. You should create the ImageSource through BitmapImage and set BitmapImage.CacheOption property to BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad:

```
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();

// Begin initialization.
bi.BeginInit();

// Set properties.
bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
// 
bi.EndInit();
```

[More Details about BitmapImage.CacheOption on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.cacheoption.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It's telling you exactly what's wrong; another process is currently accessing the file.

See [here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-1967958.php) for some suggestions as to how you can identify that process.

Comment: i know and probably the process is the visual studio but i dunno why, when i open the picture and get it into an image how can i dispose it 
so i can delete it from the file?